# iOS push notification: how to store push notification payload when application is kill or terminate in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am sending multiple push notification using firebase. My application getting all notification. Now how to store all push notifications data in user default when application is killed or terminate?
How to store all push notifications data when application is killed and the user click one push notification from all notification?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is not getting invoked just with a push notifications. What you receive in the Notification tray is handled by iOS directly and the content of the push notification, specifically what is inside aps key of the Notification body is used to populate the content you see in the notification tray.

The app will not get invoked just because you received a push notification if the app is in suspended or killed state.
Unless of course your apns-push-type is set as background and content-available = 1 in your notification.
The call would go to

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

Where you may process the contents as required by the app.

To detect if the app was launched from a Notification,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    if let dict = launchingOptions?[.remoteNotification]{
        //App launched from Notification 
        if let userInfo = dict as? [AnyHashable:Any]{
            //Do what your app requires with the notification using the userInfo.
        }
    }
}
```